# Error level not changing when file is ran with psexec

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp, psexec

I have one piece of code that is behaving differently when I ran it on server and when I ran it with psexec. I'm actually trying to determent is computer offline, but that is not question here. Problem is that when I run this command directly on server errorlevel is changing to 1, because pc is online. But when I use psexec to run file with same commands on that server errorelevel is not changing it stays 0. I cant find any explanations on internet.

```
echo %errorlevel%

ping -n 1 machine | findstr "not" > nul
IF %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo test
)

echo %errorlevel%

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

What you show is not a command, but a batch file, say `ping_machine.cmd`. To call it from `psexec` the command line would be something like `psexec \\server cmd /c ping_machine.cmd`. If I guessed wrong you may stop reading the rest of this answer now (and next time post enough relevant context so that one doesn't have to guess).

Problem is that `cmd /c` returns the exit code of `ping_machine`, but the batch file does not explicitly set an exit code, so it returns 0 by default. This can be verified at the cmd prompt with the following 2 runs - note that inside the batch file you see the same/correct errorlevels, but `cmd /c` returns `0`.

```
C:\etc>ping_machine
0
1
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\etc>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\etc>cmd /c ping_machine
0
1
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\etc>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

To have `cmd /c` behave as you expect (and in turn `psexec` as well), add the following line at the end of the batch file to return the respective errorlevel (this works because neither `echo` nor `pause` modify the `errorlevel`, otherwise you'd have to save it in a temp variable for later use).

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Problem is that I have batch file what I'm running with pcexec command. In that batch file I have some code that is using `%errorlevel%` for comparing. Problem is in this; When I run that file locally `%errorlevel%` is changing accordingly, but when I run this file on remote machine `%errorlevel%` is not changing it is staying 0.

Comment: @IGRACH Please post the complete psexec line and batch file(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

There it is. When I run this batch file locally errorlevel is changed to 9009. When I use `psexec \\computername -f -c pathToFile` , error code is staying 0.

```
@echo off
echo %errorlevel%
pin 234343
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```